# How to count webservice calls?

Tags: web-services, glassfish-3, jmx

I would like to know how many times a webservice is invoked (called), which is deployed on glassfish AS 3.1?
Is it possible to know it using JMX interface? if so, what is the ObjectName?

Besides that I can get this value from Command interface with the following command statement

> asadmin get -m "server.applications.hello-jaxws2*"
>   server.applications.hello-jaxws2.2.server.Hello.requestcount-count = 14

Thanks in advance

Comment: # asadmin get -m "server.applications.hello-jaxws2*"   
server.applications.hello-jaxws2\.2.server.Hello.requestcount-count = 14

Comment: following link canbe used to get webservice request count [link](http://localhost:4848/__asadmin/get?monitor=true&DEFAULT=server.applications.hello-jaxws2\.2.server.Hello.requestcount-count). But still needs to get it via JMX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## asadmin get -m "server.applications.hello-jaxws2*" server.applications.hello-jaxws2.2.server.Hello.requestcount-count = 14

I could not found how to get web service call invocation count. But Restful interface of AS is enought for me.